# MYSQL error REGEXP con caracteres alfabeto AFI (ɾ, ɲ, ɱ, ɣ...)

Tags: mysql, regex

En mysql la siguiente consulta, como es de esperar, devuelve 0 (Falso):

```
SELECT 'ɾ' REGEXP 'ɲ';
```

Sin embargo, la siguiente consulta, inesperadamente, devuelve 1 (Verdadero):

```
SELECT 'ɾ' REGEXP '[ɲ]';
```

La cuestión es que necesito los corchetes, porque necesito hacer algo como esto:

```
SELECT 'ɾ' REGEXP '[bβθkdʣðfgɣhjʒʤʎmɱnŋɲprsʃʧtʦvxz]';
```

He comprobado que la presencia entre corchetes de alguno de los caracteres ɲ, ɱ, ɣ, da como resultado 1, y que si quito esos tres caracteres devuelve 0. La solución que se me ha ocurrido ha sido convertir la expresión en la siguiente, entonces sí que obtengo 0:

```
SELECT 'ɾ' REGEXP '(ɣ|ɱ|ɲ|[bβθkdʣðfghjʒʤʎmnŋprsʃʧtʦvxz])';
```

Sin embargo, me interesaría poder utilizar la otra expresión, puesto que en mi aplicación la expresión regular es configurable por el usuario y necesito facilitarle las cosas.

¿Sabéis decirme por qué ocurre esto y si hay una solución? Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes estar usando mysql 5. Parece un problema con el uso de caracteres unicode y expresiones regulares.

Y el motivo es probablemente el siguiente:

Como sabrás, la expresión `[ab]` significa `un caracter que puede ser 'a' o 'b'`.

Pero si se usa un motor de expresiones regulares que no está pensando para soportar unicode, como parece ser el caso de Mysql 5, esto es lo que pasa cuando escribes `[ɲ]`

El caracter `ɲ` está [formado](https://graphemica.com/%C9%B2) por dos bytes (o dos caracteres): 0xC9 0xB2.

Con lo que al utilizar eso como clase, lo que estás diciendo es: un caracter que puede ser `0xC9` o `0xB2`.

Por contra, el caracter `ɾ` está [formado](https://graphemica.com/%C9%BE) por 0xC9 0xBE.

Así que para Mysql 5, realmente lo que está entendiendo es esto:

```
SELECT '0xC9 0xBE' REGEXP '[0xC9 0xB2]'; -- Sólo para entendernos
```

Y como puede encontrar 0xC9, te devuelve verdadero.

La situación está [resuelta](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7079f9db9f0066bbcf4395befb77de1) en Mysql 8, ya que trata correctamente los grupos de caracteres unicode como un único caracter.

Si tienes que seguir usando Mysql 5, entonces lo único que se me ocurre es lo que ya has comentado, dividirlo por subexpresiones `(a|b|c|...)`

Para facilitarle el trabajo al usuario, podrías admitir una entrada que permita clases de caracteres `[]`, que luego tú mismo te encargues de transformar en subexpresiones. Mientras lo que utilices para hacerlo soporte caracteres unicode, no tendrías que tener problema.

Answer (score 3):

Una [situación similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482531/how-to-make-mysql-aware-of-multi-byte-characters-in-like-and-regexp) se expone en StackOverflow, en donde la respuesta aceptada sugiere que se utilice `HEX()`: al recibir como argumento un string, esta función convierte cada caracter de la cadena en dos dígitos hexadecimales (como lo menciona la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex)).
Así, por ejemplo, lo que mencionabas:

> Sin embargo, la siguiente consulta, inesperadamente, devuelve 1
>   (Verdadero):
>
> ```
> SELECT 'ɾ' REGEXP '[ɲ]';
> ```

devuelve '0' cuando lo escribís de esta manera:

```
SELECT HEX('ɾ') REGEXP '[ɲ]';
```

y esto:

```
SELECT 'ɾ' REGEXP '[bβθkdʣðfgɣhjʒʤʎmɱnŋɲprsʃʧtʦvxz]';
```

podrías convertirlo en:

```
SELECT HEX('ɾ') REGEXP HEX('[bβθkdʣðfgɣhjʒʤʎmɱnŋɲprsʃʧtʦvxz]');
```

(que si devuelve cero, en este caso).

Debés tener en cuenta que estás trabajando con caracteres multibyte, es por eso que tenés resultados inesperados. De hecho, en la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) se advierte (traducción aproximada):

> Los operadores REGEXP y RLIKE trabajan byte a byte (...) y pueden producir resultados inesperados con conjuntos de caracteres multibyte.

**Edit**: Es cierto, la solución que te propuse no es "universal". Como lo menciona @Julio, este comportamiento "errático" se soluciona en la versión 8 de MySQL.
De ser posible, también podrías usar otros motores como MariaDB o PostgreSQL; o si estás usando MySQL < 8.0 y tenés acceso al servidor, también podrías instalar una librería: [lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme) (mencionado como respuesta en este [reporte de bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30241)).

Como última opción, pese a que complica al usuario final de tu aplicación, podrías utlizar esta expresión:

```
'(ɣ|ɱ|ɲ|ɾ|β|θ|ʣ|ð|ʒ|ʤ|ʎ|ŋ|ʃ|ʧ|ʦ)|[bkdfghjmnprstvxz]'
```

el cual aparta a los caracteres multibyte.

Comment: No funciona,

SELECT HEX('ɾ') REGEXP '[ɲ]';

devuelve 0, pero:

SELECT HEX('ɲ') REGEXP '[ɲ]';

y

SELECT HEX('ɲ') REGEXP HEX('[ɲ]');

también devuelven 0, y deben devolver 1.